# When will the next summer solstice and a full moon coincide? What day?

Tags: orbit, the-moon, the-sun

What day will the summer solstice and full moon coincide? As far as I know the next time will be in 2016. I would like to know what day.

Comment: You might want to think about Googling for this kind of data for yourself in future.

Comment: http://www.almanac.com/content/full-moon-winter-solstice
Last occurred in 1986.According to the article, it occurs approximately every 19yrs.

Answer (score 1):

The Summer Solstice in 2016 will occur at 22:34 UT on the 20th June, and the full moon will occur at 11:02 UT on that day (but since they are 12 hours apart that won't be on the same day everywhere).

Solstice data from [here](http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/longest-day/equinox-solstice-2010-2019.htm) (GMT- Grenwich Mean Time =UT)
[image]

New and full moon data from [here](http://www.moongiant.com/Full_Moon_New_Moon_Calendar.php) (UTC- Coordinated Universal Time =GMT=UT)
[image]